# C#: Json validation from user input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, file-io, deserialization

I need to validate a json file from server side, Im using asp.net mvc with c#, so I have this method in my controller

```
public ActionResult Validate(HttpPostedFileBase jsonFile) 
    {
        bool validJson = false;
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        try 
        {
            var result = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(How should I pass the json file here ??);
            validJson = true;
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            validJson = false;
        }

    }
```

This is the best way for validate it ? ... sorry but I don't know how to pass the json string parameter, I have tried with **jsonFile.InputStream.ToString()**, **jsonFile.tostring()** ... what it needs ?, json user's route ? ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well how about something like this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile.InputStream))
{
    string jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var result = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonData);
    // dragons be here ...
}
```

Comment: could you explain to me please, why after **using** command, I try to save my file and It´s empty, after validate json I need to save some records in db and after all, save my file. But It's only working inside using, and I need it after it ... thank you

Comment: You need to save the JSON like: `jsonFile.SaveAs("c:\\fullfilepath");`

Comment: Ok that's exactly what I'm doing but I always get and empty file, I'm trying without those lines and It saves good. I need to save it inside using tag ?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure, basically it's disposing of the `StreamReader`, I'm surprised it's affecting the original InputStream. I'll run some tests.